# Running a command multiple times with arguments (filenames) from a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have a file with a long list of filenames (with full paths).  I've also got a program I'd like to run multiple times, using one and one filename from this list as argument.  The program I'd like to run, is sadly a self-made script; so it can only take *one* filename at a time, and it cannot accept input from **stdin** (like a list of filenames) - so no piping or input-redirection possible.

What I need, is a command that will run *another* command (my script), using the lines in the file as argument.

Something like `find` with the `-exec`-action... (`find . -name "*.txt" -exec command \;` ).  I guess I actually *could* use `find` here, but I'd like for the input-files to be sorted...

So what I need is something like this:

```
for_each_command1 -f list_of files -c './my_command {}'
for_each_command2 -f list_of_files -exec ./my_command {} \;
for_each_command3 -c './my_command {}' 

My usual way to handle such tasks is with sed - unfortunately, there's a lot of overhead and it's not pretty (but it does work...):


$ wc -l list_of_files
232
$ for (( i=1; i do
> ./my_command "`sed -n "${i}p" list_of_files`"
> done
```

So is there a command or shell built-in to handle something like this?

Comment: Also see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943) which covers how to correctly use `find ... -exec`.

Comment: @Wildcard Usually it's not - and I'd usually do just that...  But *this* time I wanted the file-list - and the subsequent list resulting from my script - to be in alphabetical order, and `find` does not output files in alphabetical order.  Yes, you can `sort` the output of `find ... -print`(which is what I've done to make the file-list), but the file-order from `find` is not alphabetical.  What my script does to the list - the information it parse from the files in the list - makes it far easier to sort the file-list *first*, than try to alphabetically sort the result *afterwards*.

Comment: That doesn't actually make a difference; there are still better solutions.  File globbing (including `zsh` file globbing extensions) are one approach.  I've posted [another, even simpler answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336218/135943) below.  I still recommend you actually read through all the information at the page I linked above.

Answer (score 6):

Conveniently, `xargs -I` does exactly what you want:

```
$ xargs <my_file_list.txt -I filename ./my_command "filename"
```

> ```
> -I replace-str
>     Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read
>     from standard input.
>     Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items;
>     instead the separator is the newline character.
>     Implies -x and -L 1.
> ```

This means it takes exactly one newline-delimited input line and invokes your command with it as a single argument. Nothing apart from newline is treated as a delimiter, so spaces and other special characters are fine.

Note that if you wanted to allow newlines in your filenames, the nul terminator (as per Wildcard's answer) will also work in a file.

Comment: Apart from being slightly obfuscated by having the redirection first on the command line, this is a good solution.

Comment: Moved - I tend to put input redirection at the start, and output redirection at the end, out of some probably-misplaced feeling of symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

I assumes your list of files is stored in a file named 'filelist.txt', each file name in a line. Then you can call your script with each line as an argument as follow:

```
while read name; do
  ./yoursrcipt.sh "$name"
done <filelist.txt
```

Comment: Assuming the file names have e.g. no spaces in them. Better to set the `$IFS` for the `read`.

Comment: @phk Oh there are spaces - lots of 'em... and exclamation-marks, and parenthesis...

Comment: @BaardKopperud Then use `while IFS= read -r name; do`.

Answer (score 3):

I usually prefer portable (POSIX) solutions, but the *simple, obvious* answer here is to use GNU extensions to make your life easier:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -n1 -r0 ./mycommand
```

This uses null bytes as separators between filenames, which is important since filenames can contain *any* character, including newlines.

(Slashes are also reserved, since they are path component separators, but that doesn't matter in this context because you can't use them as file delimiters.)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed < list_of_files 's,^,./mycommand ",;s,$,",' | sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat baard.in
/path/to/some space file
/some   tabbed/some     tabbed  file
/path to/genericfile
/path/to/regular.file
/path/to/exciting!/file!
/path/to/(parenthetical)/file.txt

$ cat my_command
#!/bin/sh
printf "my_command: %s\n" "$1"
```

Since awk already parses lines, you could use it to call your command with each record, being careful to quote the parameter:

```
$ awk '{system("./my_command '\''" $0 "'\''");}' < baard.in
my_command: /path/to/some space file
my_command: /some       tabbed/some     tabbed  file
my_command: /path to/genericfile
my_command: /path/to/regular.file
my_command: /path/to/exciting!/file!
my_command: /path/to/(parenthetical)/file.txt
```

The awk command fails if there are single quotes in the input, though, such as:

```
/books/Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.epub
```

If you have bash available, you could use:

```
$ readarray -t paths < baard.in
$ for((i=0;i < ${#paths[*]}; i++)); do ./my_command "${paths[i]}"; done
my_command: /path/to/some space file
my_command: /some       tabbed/some     tabbed  file
my_command: /path to/genericfile
my_command: /path/to/regular.file
my_command: /path/to/exciting!/file!
my_command: /path/to/(parenthetical)/file.txt
my_command: /books/Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.epub
```

or in ksh93 (hat-tip to [Gilles' answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159268/117549) for the manual implementation of readarray):

```
$ IFS=$'\n'; set -f
$ paths=( $(< baard.in) )
$ unset IFS; set +f
$ for((i=0;i < ${#paths[*]}; i++)) do ./my_command "${paths[i]}"; done
my_command: /path/to/some space file
my_command: /some       tabbed/some     tabbed  file
my_command: /path to/genericfile
my_command: /path/to/regular.file
my_command: /path/to/exciting!/file!
my_command: /path/to/(parenthetical)/file.txt
my_command: /books/Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.epub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this should do what you need (assuming your file has one filename per line):

```
for i in `cat list_of_files`; do ./mycommand "$i"; done
```

Comment: It ought to... but I've found that it often doesn't work with filenames with spaces and such embedded (each word is treated as a filename) - hence my `sed`-hack.  It's possible there are some options that prevent this, but in general I've had little success with `cat`ing and `xargs`ing long lists of files.

Comment: `for` performs usual expansion and splitting on whatever comes after `in`. There's no reliable way to do this with `cat`.

Comment: @BaardKopperud: the use of " around `$i` should take care of spaces and other unusual characters in the filename (except for `*`, `?` and other special characters which get expanded by the shell).

Answer (score 0):

as i understand it you have asked how to read an infile and run a task for each line read.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do    mycmd "$line"
done  < infile
```

or if you want to sort your input first:

```
sort ./infile[123] |
while IFS= read -r line
do    mycmd "$line"
done
```