# Why doesn't SIGSTOP work inside screen session?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, signals

Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OFILE='log'
echo 'ok' > ${OFILE}
kill -SIGSTOP $$
echo 'after stop' > ${OFILE}
```

In an interactive shell the script is stopped and the output is `ok`. However, if it is started as

```
screen -d -m ./test.sh
```

the output is `after stop`. Does screen handle the signal? How to suspend a process in a screen session?

Comment: Have you used `echo $$`?

Comment: Yes, I checked that `$$` is a PID of bash. Another interesting thing is that if I run the script without dettaching the session then screen informs that "child has been stopped, restarting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examination of the [source code of GNU screen-4.0.2](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/screen-4.0.2.tar.gz) showed that screen checks if its child processes are stopped and then tries to resume them with SIGCONT. Here is a relevant part of the `screen.c`:

```
1561 if (WIFSTOPPED(wstat))
1562   {   
1563     debug3("Window %d pid %d: WIFSTOPPED (sig %d)\n", p->w_number, p->w_pid, WSTOPSIG(wstat));
....
1578     /* Try to restart process */
1579     Msg(0, "Child has been stopped, restarting.");
1580     if (killpg(p->w_pid, SIGCONT))
1581       kill(p->w_pid, SIGCONT);
1582   }
```

It seems this behaviour cannot be changed with an option or via a config file. The suggested solution to stop screen process might have undesirable side effects. A better approach is to hide stopped process from the screen. For a bash script this can be done with a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
(   
OFILE='log'
echo 'ok' > ${OFILE}
kill -SIGSTOP ${BASHPID}
echo 'after stop' > ${OFILE}
)
```

For other shells it might be not so straightforward, e.g. for tcsh:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
(\  
set OFILE='log' ;\
echo 'ok' > ${OFILE} ;\
kill -STOP `exec sh -c 'echo ${PPID}'` ;\
echo 'after stop' > ${OFILE} \
)
```

The key difference is the method to get PID of the subshell, more info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32595/65213).

Alternatively, the script can be started without modification with a [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/3476320) script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTDIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f -n "$0")")"
${SCRIPTDIR}/test.sh
```

To run:

```
screen -d -m ./wrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the screen process is restarting the stopped bash process. I tried following (sending SIGSTOP signal to both of the processes):

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
OFILE='log'
echo 'ok' > ${OFILE}
echo 'screen pid ' $(screen -list | grep sc_test | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/\W//g') >> ${OFILE}
echo 'test.sh pid ' $$ >> ${OFILE}
kill -SIGSTOP $(screen -list | grep sc_test | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/\W//g')
kill -SIGSTOP $$
echo 'after stop' >> ${OFILE}
```

screen command

```
screen -dmS sc_test ./test.sh
```

log file

```
ok
screen pid  4453
test.sh pid  4454
```

listing screens

```
screen -list
There is a screen on:
        4453.sc_test    (11/05/2015 10:45:20 AM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```